# Querying with `skip` and `limit`: return the paginated documents, and Total count

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

i am defining a standard query:

```
query = Order.collection.find(
  {
    "company_id" => company._id
  },{
    projection: {
      _id: 1,
      order_number: 1
    },
    sort: { _id: -1 }
  }
)
```

I then paginate my query by combining `skip` and `limit`:

```
query.skip(0).limit(1).to_a
```

In a seperate action I count how many documents match the query:

```
query.count()
```

Is there a way to combine the two actions, and get back both informations in the same response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aggregation framework is flexible enough to give you both informations in one query:

```
db.Order.aggregate([
  { $match: { company_id: company._id } },
  { $sort: { "_id": -1 } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      count: { $sum: 1 },
      firstItem: { $first: "$$ROOT" }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      count: 1,
      _id: "$firstItem._id",
      order_number: "$firstItem.order_number"
    }
  }
])
```

Ordering is performed on filtered set of documents. Then we're using `$first` to do the pagination and `$sum` to count the items. `_id` equal to null means that we're grouping entire set. Last step with `$project` is just to narrow down the result to the fields that you need.